# How to get this effect (don't know what it is called?!?!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, effect

There is a site called http://www.nomomon.com, and when a user signs in there is a box that pops up saying 'connected to server', and welcome back etc etc...

To see what I mean go to the site and login with the email lazycg@live.co.uk and the password: pass

You will see what I mean, I just don't know how to go about creating this effect, any ideas??

Comment: I gave you an email and password to login with!!

Comment: @Tomalak he provided with an example username and password so you can log in without signing up.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, then. ;-) Still, a screenshot or something would be a lot better than putting your account details into public.

Comment: @carlgcoder: maybe you can add a screenshot to your question?

Answer (score 1):

One name for the technique you're thinking of would be "lightbox". There are many existing scripts to achieve such an effect. A quick search for "[JavaScript lightbox](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript%20lightbox&surl=1)" will return thousands of results.

Personally, I tend to use [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) if I'm already using jQuery. Have a look at the modal example in the jQuery UI docs to find something similar to the example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a modal window: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

This a live example that you can use: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-message

With some modification you could get a similar effect. Use a darker background, do some AJAX requests to update the message shown then redirect the user.

Answer (score -1):

That effect is called a lightbox, it's obtainable by simply having an half transparent overlay over the page, and on top of that, a `<div>` which is animated with jQuery. The text changes, probably according to the AJAX call results, that's about all there is to it.

Answer (score -1):

Their code in http://www.nomomon.com/ui/login.js is obscured, but I'd approach this with a tool like xajax ... http://www.xajax-project.org ... which can easily access call both PHP and javascript/jQuery functions. Doing a MySQL query, updating the DOM with jQuery, doing another MySQL query, updating the DOM again, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The effect in jquery is called a lightbox. The one used on that site looks very similar to [FancyBox](http://designresourcebox.com/fancybox-lighbox-jquery-plugin/). I'm willing to bet it is fancy box with a custom skin.